Connect to MS CRM Dataverse using IBM DataStage(ETL)
Currently using Microsoft CRM Dynamics on premise.  We extract data from it every night using IBM DataStage and then report from that using COGNOS Analytics.
We are now moving to Microsoft CRM 365 SaaS.  We would like to continue using Data Stage to extract and transform our data but we have no idea at present if we can do this or if we need to move technologies.  We have been told that our data will be available in DataVerse but have no guidance on how to get the data extracted.
Has anyone done something similar to this?  Any steps without using cdata software maybe?
Trying to find ways without using cdata software. if no other way will look into maybe the cdata route.

A really good tool that I use to perform ETL tasks to and from Dynamics is Kingswaysoft And SSIS packages. These can run on prem with a SQL Server or in the cloud using Azure Data Factory and an Azure SSIS integration runtime service.
Azure data factory can link directly to dataverse as well and you can perform ETL
Tasks and jobs but it could be more costly that way than going SSIS IR route.
Another way would be to utilize the Dynamics export data functionality using Azure Synapse and then pushing to Azure Datalake, but this too is quite costly in my opinion Kingswaysoft fits my needs and does so brilliantly.
Here’s a link to the product i am referring to.
KingsWaySoft Productivity Kit for Dynamics

Any affiliation?

Affliation to KWS? No, its a ETL tool that I use and know works to extract data from Dataverse. I dont know of any solution using IBM datastage.
